# GAE ImagesService().getServingUrl() is to long executed. Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, thumbnails

I want to create thumbs for blobstore files.
I use code:

String servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(
                ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(new BlobKey(blobKey))
                        .imageSize(100)
                        .secureUrl(false)
        );

It work fine. But when I need to create many thums per one request I get exception:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (2b0af6acab1f5e18) started at 2012/10/11 21:53:57.444 UTC and was still executing at 2012/10/11 21:54:57.017 UTC.
```

Maybe someone have solution for this problem. Please help!

Comment: If you receive a DeadlineExceededException: retry. That solved my problems.

Comment: use PHP instead of java you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646849/how-can-we-use-firebase-image-file-and-resize-them-using-get-serving-url/37673504#37673504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task queue was designed for long running tasks like this, you should look into it.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview?hl=en

Comment: Ok. One also question if I use this code - String servingUrl = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl( ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(new BlobKey(blobKey)) .imageSize(100) .secureUrl(false) ); - twice, in second call it will working faster?

Comment: I don't see why it would be faster the second time.

Comment: Then why should I use long running tasks?
I need create page with many small images. But I can`t because method getServingUrl get long time.
The method getServingUrl I understand how - "give me ulr for thumbs and no more". When thumbs will be created I don`t know but I think not every time when called method  getServingUrl(maybe never).

Comment: Call getServingUrl() once (in the task queue), and cache the url somewhere (ie datastore).  For all requests that need the images, you use the url from the datastore rather than via getServingUrl().