# how can we use firebase image file and resize them using get_Serving_URL

Tags: image, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I just started using google cloud services 
and found that the following can be only implemented using blob but i want to use image name from cloud storage.

Is there a way to resize the images using servingURL if so 
how can i implement it i.e. how can i give the bucket name and image name from cloud storage ?

and construct the URL and pass the parameters

is there any blog or code that i can refer ?

Answer (score 1):

The [get_serving_url()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images) is part of App Engine and thus you can't use it in Firebase (unless Firebase will eventually supports it), but you can definitely [store the images in the Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) instead of Blobstore, which is by the way is the recommended way.

Comment: then how can i resize the Image .I tried the documentation in this link but its incomplete https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/images/ .there is no reference on how i can pass cloud storage image name

Answer (score 1):

here is the blog to resize the image

This is the sample PHP code but how to make it working in FireBase you need to refer the link below 
[click here to read more](http://cloud-clinic.blogspot.com/2016/06/dynamic-image-resize-from-google-cloud.html)

```js
index.php:

<?php
//var_dump($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name']);
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Request came");
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Imported Cloud Storage Tools");
//var_dump( $_GET);
$object_url=$_GET["image"];
$size=intval($_GET["size"]);
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Object URL $object_url");
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Size $size");

$bucket="gs://YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com/bucket_name/";
$object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_url,['size' => $size, 'crop' => false]);
syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Output Url $object_image_url");
header("location: $object_image_url");

closelog();
?>



app.yaml:

runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Javascript SDK to send your files to Google Storage, and build an API samples with PHP + library from AppEngine for generating the URL of the object, are same bucket locate.

In app PHP, remember to put following content in `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Before, using `gcloud`, deploy your sample API:

```
gcloud app deploy
```