# google cloud storage - getServingUrl() giving URL of old image

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am uploading an image on the GCS and then overwriting it with a different with same file name (image.png). In the GCS browser, I can see the image being overwritten (different size, timestamp) but when I try to get the URL of the image using getServingUrl() I get the URL of the image that I uploaded the very first time!!!

If I add an image with a new file name (image2.png) then I get a new URL. If I overwrite this image with another one (keeping the name as image2.png) then once again I get the URL for original image2.png.

Here is my code:

```
String bucketName = "my_bucket_name";
    String userFileName = "image.png";
    try {
        GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
        GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(bucketName, userFileName);// getFileName(request);
        GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
        gcsService.delete(fileName);
        outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
        copy(request.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    String url = imagesService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName("/gs/" +
            bucketName + "/" + userFileName).secureUrl(true));
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here? How to get the ImagesService to give me the handle to newly uploaded image? Thanks.

Comment: use PHP instead of java you can refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646849/how-can-we-use-firebase-image-file-and-resize-them-using-get-serving-url/37673504#37673504

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. The object can be cached in any of the intermediary proxy servers which you have no control over. So, setting a Cache Control header also may not solve the issue.

When uploading the file, instead of saving it with the filename, you could use the md5hash of the file as the name. This would ensure if the file contents change, you will have a different md5hash. With this approach, you can also use cache control headers and it would speed up the loading of your web page

Comment: Guess you are right. Using hash value or any unique name seems to be the right way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As java_geek pointed you, hou have probably encountered a known App Engine bug: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11381

If you want to always serve the live version of a GCS object, and you don't need any of the special properties of App Engine image serving, you can create objects with the "cacheControl" property set to something like "no-cache", and then link to them via this URL:

```
http(s)://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name
```

This will serve the image directly from GCS.

Comment: No, this didn't help. I gave cacheControl("private") as you suggested and also tested this on a different machine so that if it is a problem created due to browser, it gets resolved . It still gives same URL. I am testing in Postman and there too it gives same URL.

Comment: Interesting. What if you serve it directly from GCS by serving a URL like 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/object_name" ?

Comment: This solution wont work. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11381

Comment: Oh, interesting! I will amend my response.